# Why DISTNICT is not working in spark sql?

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

My Code :

```
String selectedColumns = "name,age";
String dataFrameName ="student";
Dataset<Row> datasets =sparksession.sql("SELECT DISTINCT "+selectedColumns+"FROM"+dataFrameName);
```

with the above code I am getting duplicate row not the distinct one
I tried the below approach but still distinct is not working

```
Dataset<Row> distnictDs =datasets.distinct();
Dataset<Row> distnictDs1 =datasets.dropDuplicates("name","age");
```

Nothing is working, How to retrieve only distinct row from a dataset in spark ?

Comment: Do you get any errors, caused by missing spaces?

Comment: no , i am not getting any error , i am getting the dataset also bot not the distinct one